# Get LocalStorage file for app's browser in the Java code

Tags: java, android, cordova, local-storage

I have a Cordova android application, which is basically an in-app browser window, that has a local storage file somewhere, where I save data from the app. I want to access this local storage file from the Java code now, but I don't know how. How can I do that?

- Searched in Google before asking.
- No code to show, because there is
  nothing relevant to show.

Comment: that thing: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebStorage.html ?

Comment: @njzk2 I dont know, I only know that the cordova app is in a in-app browser window

Answer (score 0):

See
[Cordova file plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)
and
[Exploring file APIs](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Comment: that does not help me, I need to access it from the Java code, not from javascript

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the Q properly.  Is the file you want to access the browser cache ? Why do you have to access via Java and not Javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova is just a container to let you get access to device APIs with html, css, and javascript. When you use something like `localStorage`, it gets stored in whatever browser the phone uses (iOS would be Safari, Android varies).

Use `localStorage.getItem(idOfTheItemYouStored)` to get access to whatever file you are looking for. If you don't know what you named it, you can use a for loop to loop through and log each item as so:

```
for(var i in localStorage) {
    console.log(localStorage[i]);
}
```

Comment: read my question please, I need to access the local storage from the native Java code